# Copying data from Centos hard drive to Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a 2 PCs wiht ubuntu 10.04 and centos 5.8 installed.I want to copy all the data from Centos hard drive to one with ubuntu. How can I do this ???

I have tried directly plugging centos hard drive with Ubuntu running PC. But centos hard drive is not visible in ubuntu.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: What is you Centos hard drive formatted as?

Comment: It should be visible, unless something is wrong with it. Can you plug it in again, run `dmesg | tail` in a terminal and add the output to the question.